# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Atom D2500 Netbook?

Tags: 16.04, intel-atom

I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Atom D2500 netbook but it just boot into black screen after I select install in the boot menu. I realized it might be the lack of graphic processing file in the installation disk. I like to know what I can do to install Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen if you choose "Try Ubuntu" instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/a/956010/304864) people say 12.04 version worked fine. It's a bad idea to install old system though, so given the circumstances, I'd advice to try [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) instead. It has more later drivers, kernel, and such, and possibly may not have the problem.

Comment: @JamesWayne please tell if it worked or not.

Comment: @Hi-Angel so far not really. It did boot into the command line but cannot enter the graphic interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither Try Ubuntu or install would work. Ubuntu does not access D2500's graphic processor at all. You simply cannot use the installer to install Ubuntu whatsoever.

Perhaps there is a way to install Ubuntu through command line interface somehow, but it is beyond me. Stick with Windows 7 32bit, it seems to be the only OS D2500 supports fully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a number of posts about it, [this one may serve as a summation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265712/59928) of the situation.

In short, some time ago Intel made a deal with Imagination Technologies for PowerVR GPUs, and they ought to make the drivers, not Intel. The only "Intel" in those GPUs is the brand they named after. In retrospective it turned out to be a bad deal: though GNU/Linux and Windows7 x86-32 supported drivers at some point of time, but kernel evolved on, whilst drivers didn't. More over, even when drivers worked, it was full of problems on all supported OSes.

There's just two solutions: either to install an older system, or [to use modesetting driver](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA_3600) *(I'm not sure about its limitations, perhaps missing 3d support?)*. If you're going to go with modesetting driver, that means you need somehow to install the system before trying it out. As I see, there's two ways to do it:

- to install Ubuntu through another PC, then modify configuration accordingly to the article, then carry the medium with the installed system to the notebook. This have advantage of being fast to do and check if it's working. This is the recommended way, if you have an opportunity to.
- [to install the original distro](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide), Archlinux, owning the wiki page. The advantage here is that installation doesn't require graphics, there's no need to compare package names on the Wiki with Ubuntu ones, and in general Archlinux tends to be faster *(I'm writing the text from Arch)*. But if you're new, it would take too much time.

In general, even if modesetting fail, you still definitely can run GNU/Linux on the notebook, e.g. with VESA *(does PowerVR support VESA standard? I'm wondering why doesn't Ubuntu installer falls back to it)*, or even software rendering, like *llvmpipe*. That might not be too encouraging, but given that PowerVR chips have never had OS that supported them good, it's not that bad.

Ask me if you need any further help with this.